# How to make 1 variable is equal to multiple values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, facebook

Hello I want to add friends on facebook using tokens..

I found this code.

```
edprens: function(a) {
        if (aingFA.tueds.length >= 500 || a == "sisa") {
            $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends", {
                method: "post",
                uids: USER ID/NAME I WANT TO ADD,
                access_token: token
            }, function(h) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(h))
            });
            aingFA.tueds = []
        }
    },
```

example I have.. ids

"100000832430xxx"

"100001934154xxx"

"100004994917xxx"

"100002314479xxx"

"100001092002xxx"

"100001801769xxx"

How to make "uids" is equal to above ids.. so I can add them.?

Thank you

Comment: Pass them like parameter to your function. What have you tried to do already? No one will do your work for you.

Comment: @vladkras I already successfully send request when I make.. "uids: 100001801769xxx,"
but I want to make a bulk.. send request.. not 1 by 1 :(

Comment: so call `edprens()` function as many times as you need in a loop

Comment: @vladkras thanks for the response but how I can do that? I came up with this edprens("ids###");edprens("ids###");edprens("ids###");.. and uids: a, but its not working..

Comment: BTW, you can't do a POST on `/me/friends`

Answer (score 0):

It's too big to post it in comment. As I said you have to pass it like another parameter, so the function will look like:

```
edprens: function(a, id) { 
             ... 
             uids: id, // USER ID/NAME YOU WANT TO ADD
             ... 
         }
```

then in a loop call it for every id

```
var IDs = ["100000832430xxx", "100004994917xxx", "100002314479xxx"]; // this is your array with IDs
for (var i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
    edprens(a, IDs[i]);
}
```

or put the loop inside the function

```
edprens: function(a, IDs) {
             ... 
             for (var i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
                 $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends", {
                     ...
                     uids: IDs[i], // USER ID/NAME YOU WANT TO ADD
                     ...
                 });
             }
             ... 
         }
```

edprens("ids###");edprens("ids###");edprens("ids###"); is not a loop. And even if you do like this parameter `a` becomes your id

Comment: @WillerjaneAyawan of course it doesn't work 1. it's a piece of code you can't just tear it from your source 2. you have a lot of mistakes in it, e.g. `,` ending and `:` assigning 3. you didn't enable jQuery in fiddle 4. `a` and `aingFA.tueds` is checked there, but you don't create any variable 5. You don't even call it!!! 6. etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

The `uids` part makes me think you might be able to simply pass in an array of ids. Otherwise use a loop:

**Here's it using a loop which should definately work:**

```js
//create an array with your ids  
var myIds = ["100000832430xxx", "100001934154xxx", "100004994917xxx", "100002314479xxx", "100001092002xxx", "100001801769xxx"]
    
//loop through that array
$(myIds).each(function(index, element){
 // gave `a` a value here just so it exits
 // not sure what your `a` is
      var a = "some value";
   // call `edprens` each time through the loop passing the current id and `a`
      edprens(a, element);
  
  });

//change the syntax on the next line
//im not sure how to call the function with the `edprens: function(a)` syntax
function edprens(a, id) {
 
 console.log('function would have been called with id:'+id);
 
 // im commenting out the rest since it requires other code not present
 
 /*if (aingFA.tueds.length >= 500 || a == "sisa") {
  $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends", {
   method: "post",
   uids: id,
   access_token: token
  }, function(h) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(h))
  });
  aingFA.tueds = []
 }*/
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Here's it passing an array which might work?...:**

```js
//second method (possible but not sure)
//the `uids` part makes me think you might be ale to simply pass in an array of ids like:
var myIds = ["100000832430xxx", "100001934154xxx", "100004994917xxx", "100002314479xxx", "100001092002xxx", "100001801769xxx"]
var a = "some value";

// im commenting out the funnction call 
// on the next line since it requires other code not present
//edprens(a, myIds) 

//changed 
function edprens2(a, id) {
 
 if (aingFA.tueds.length >= 500 || a == "sisa") {
  $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends", {
   method: "post",
   uids: myIds, //here we supply the whole array, might work but Im not familar with the rest of the process so I cant say for sure
   access_token: token
  }, function(h) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(h))
  });
  aingFA.tueds = []
 }
};
```